# Reversing an array of structures in c++

Tags: c++

I have a structure definition as below:

```
struct Rect {
int l;  
int b;  
int h; 
};
```

The input format is :

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 12 2 3 
10 2  4  44 50 887 12 3 3
```

I have successfully implemented the program to take in the input and store in an array of Rect structures.

Now I am trying to implement a function to reverse the input and output as below:

```
12 2 3 40 50 60 10 20 30
12 3 3 44 50 887 10 2 4
```

I have tried implementing my own reverse function and use it but it didnt work, the below is my reverse function:

```
void reverseArray(Rect *arr, int start, int end)
{
    Rect *temp;
    while(start < end)
    {
        temp = &arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = *temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the desired format?, thank you.

Comment: [std::reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer about std::reverse is on the right track....but the correct way to use it is:

```
Rect* pBegin = arr + start;
Rect* pEnd = arr + end;

std::reverse(pBegin, pEnd);
```

Basically, std::reverse requires iterators and pointers are naturally iterators.

Comment: This assumes that 'begin' and 'end' are zero-indexed.

Comment: If i know exactly how many rect structs are there in the input, can i use the above solution? like in the example in the question the start =0 and end = 6, am i right?

Comment: How do i reverse line by line?

Comment: To reverse the entire array, 'start' would be 0 and 'end' would be the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use [std::reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

I would recommend to use `std::vector` instead of your arrays.

**[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42038f2a7384af0e)**

```
Rect r1{1,2,3};
Rect r2{4,5,6};
Rect r3{7,8,9};
std::vector<Rect> v = {r1, r2, r3};
std::reverse(v.begin(),v.end());

Rect arr[3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}; // works also with arrays
std::reverse(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr));
```

Comment: No need to use `std::vector` `std::reverse` operates on regular arrays as well.

Comment: @101010 How would you use it with arrays, i tried its giving me errors, can you give a small example

Comment: @Harry see my [live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73dd751b2fbbf870). As 101010 said, you can use your arrays.

Comment: @coincoin The error i get when i get when i use it on arrays is that: no member named 'begin' in 'Rect'

Comment: @coincoin i just tried doing this: cout << "begin" << rect.begin() << endl; where Rect *rect;

Comment: @Harry you need to use do something like that `std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));`

Comment: @coincoin didnt work: "candidate template ignored: could not match '_Tp [_Np]' against 'Rect *'"

Comment: @coincoin using `std::begin` and `std::end` in the function as you suggest will not work as there is no overload for a pointer type.  `std::begin` relies on the container having `begin()` member function or that the type passed is an array.

Comment: @NathanOliver and Harry It seems to work for me [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42038f2a7384af0e).

Comment: @coincoin Yes it works there as you have an array.  in the function that the OP has they have a pointer and it will not work with that.  see this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6018cd07dfcb9634

Answer (score 0):

Rect* temp is a pointer, this means that you are holding the address of your arr[start] in your temp value. Not the value of the struct. So when you say arr[start] = arr[end] arr[start] now contains a new value. But because temp is just pointing at that location in memory *temp will now equal the new value as well. You need to make a copy of the struct into temp and not just hold a pointer. Something along the lines of:

```
void reverseArray(Rect arr, int start, int end)
{
    Rect temp;
    while(start < end)
    {
        temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Man I am bad at explaining things.